# Keeping CSS Element Active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a button to stay active after I clicked it (opacity changed).
How can I do that using CSS ?
I already tried the :active and :enabled class, but they don't work.

Appreciating a working solution.

If it's not possible in CSS, can someone help me to do that switch in jquery ?

Comment: Use the :visited pseudo-class

Comment: @Diodeus: He didn't say it was a link...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with pure CSS.

This is an example with jQuery and CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/hrPcU/

```
$('#btn').on('click', function(e){
    //Toggle:
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    //Activate just once:
    //$(this).addClass('active');
});​
```

---

Edit (->comments):

If you want to switch the class back if you click anywhere outside the button, try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hrPcU/1/

```
$(document).on('click', function(e){
    //Check if the event was fired from the button
    if($(e.target).attr('id') != 'btn'){
        $('#btn').removeClass('active');
    }else{
        $('#btn').toggleClass('active');  
    }
});
```

​

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply !
Is there also a way to toggle the class back when clicking outside the btn ? (I think there's some "oneclick() ? )

Comment: Thanks for the nice jsfiddle. You are great !
Just wondering (for performance optimization):

At the moment we check on every mouse-click if we are on the button or not.
But wouldn't it be possible (and wiser) to use the jquery .one (http://api.jquery.com/one/) to only fire the event once ?

Comment: Of course the solution with `$(document).on();` is not very good for the performance because all click events bubble up to `document`. If it really works for you if you to use `one`, try it. I don't think it's going to work like you want because as soon as you click somewhere, the event gets executed for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

- create a CSS class that has similar style to your `:active`
- add a click handler to that element
- in that handler, append the class to that element using `addClass`

Here's concept code:

```
a:active,   /*native active pseudo-class*/
a.active {  /*your make-shift active class*/
    /*styles*/
}

$('a').on('click',function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try use: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#target-pseudo

example: http://webdesignernotebook.com/examples/target.html